# C++ Message Processing Design Discussion

Tags: c++, multithreading, list, vector, queue

I have recently coded up a multithreaded program that essentially handles two types of messages. The first is received and just pushed back in a list. Lets call this Msg_1. The second is does the same thing as Msg_1 and we shall call this Msg_2. The program is needs to monitor Msg_2 (which is received on the same network connection as Msg_1: i.e. same port/ip.) such that when it receives a valid Msg_2 it needs to look through all Msg_1's and find a match.

Right now I have the receive and pushing onto my two lists handled by one thread and the searching handled by another thread. There are pitfalls that I see in the code but it works (for now...). I had a few questions for the general community on best practices since I am also learning as I go along with this project...

First off - if I use a list and always pushback on the Msg_2 list but pop off the front will I run into an issue with how my lists are kept? I.e. If thread 1 is pushing while thread 2 is popping Msg_2 will there be an issue? Should I be locking this or at least storing what I am searching for then quickly popping as to let thread 1 be able to push if needed?

Secondly, I am getting major heartburn for how Msg_1 is handled... I push it back onto my list. When I get Msg_2 in I initialize an iterator to look through my list of Msg_1 until I either reach the end or find a match - again not with mutex's. Is there a better way to do this such that I do not have a lock for the entire duration of the search on the whole list? (The process is trying to match 2 integer fields.)

Any insight would be helpful as again I want to learn best practices for this type of solution.

I should also mention that I am limited to C++-03 and do not have access to boost. So there are some fancy things that I cannot do...

Comment: Too broad. But, in general, it is your responsibility to properly handle concurrency in a multithreaded context. C++ code is not thread-safe by default. It is your responsibility to use mutexes, and proper locking, to implement thread-safe behavior. Nobody is going to do this for you.

Comment: For first question: you could use lock-free containers